# What is better? foreach and update map vs use list.map

Tags: scala, generics

Which of the following is better and why?

**Case 1:**

```
Map[String, String] result = Map.empty[String,String]
inputList.foreach(i => result += (i -> "hi") )
```

**Case 2:**

```
inputList.map(i => (i , "hi")).toMap
```

Comment: Better how? I can imagine scenarios where either of these 2 would be somehow better.

Comment: I would like to understand how to decide which one to use. Could you share the scenarios?

Comment: Case 1 is not valid Scala and would not work, so use case 2 :)

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok In what scenarios would case 1 be better where case 2 is an option?

Comment: Of the top of my head: interacting with Java code or other callback-based libraries where you don't have a normal flow. Or microoptimizations what hardly anyone need but these very few people who need them, need them very much. Most likely not authors cases, but i find it worth mentioning.

Comment: You could also consider `inputList.view.map(i => (i , "hi")).toMap` (or `iterator` instead of `view`) to avoid creating the intermediate list. Especially if there's more transformations in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one is best is really a matter of use case. If this was a pipeline where I would pass/transform data and turning `List[String]` to `Map[String, String]` was just part of it, I would prefer to use `.map` with `.toMap` as it makes reading, maintenance and understanding easier

```
something.
  .map(someMap)
  .filter(condition)
  .map(i => i -> "hi")
  .toMap
  .mapValues(something)
  ...
```

However, if this was used in some part of a framework that instead of `Future` or `IO`s used callbacks, and the only way for me to get the result would be appending it to something, `.foreach` would be one of options I would consider

```
val mutableMap = mutable.Map.empty[String,String]
someSadLibrary.onComplete { result =>
  result.foreach { value =>
    mutableMap += ...
  }
}
```

If the code was on a really hot path I would probably take some immutable input, then use mutable structures to build result and finally return immutable result. That would also require `.foreach` and mutation (I almost never see a reason to do it in my code, more like in libraries internals).

Long story short, `.map(...).toMap` would be *almost* always better, but in *some specific situations* where it wouldn't be an option I would consider mutation.

Comment: Unless you have to write some highly performing code these differences won't matter. In normal applications you will be most likely bounded by IO and if application is long running JVM will have some time to do optimizations which can make the differences even more insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

Case 2

This is the functional way to implement it and is clearer about what the code is actually doing. If you are concerned about performance then using a `view` gives pretty much the same code as case 1 but, again, is clearer.

And to state the obvious, if case 2 is not possible then use case 1.